# My Android App Uses CPU even after closed

Tags: android

My Application drains the battery.I have used services where a request is sent to url.The service is called from my class which extends Application.Below is my code.

```
public class GApplication extends Application {
private static final String TAG ="GApplication";
private HttpClient httpClient;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();   
    startService(new Intent(this, GService.class));
    httpClient = createHttpClient();
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory(){
    super.onLowMemory();
    shutdownHttpClient();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate(){
    super.onTerminate();
    stopService(new Intent(this, GService.class));
    shutdownHttpClient();
    databaseHelper.close();
}

private void shutdownHttpClient(){
    if(httpClient != null && httpClient.getConnectionManager() != null){
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}

public DatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper(){
    if(databaseHelper == null){
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    }
    return databaseHelper;
}

public HttpClient getHttpClient(){
    return httpClient;
}

public HttpClient createHttpClient(){
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry), params);
}

public boolean isOnline(){
    boolean isConnected = false;
    try{
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        isConnected = (info != null && info.isAvailable() && info.isConnected());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        isConnected = false;
        if(e.getMessage() != null) Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return isConnected;
}
```

}

My Gservice Class

```
public class GService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "Gservice";



public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}   


public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "starting GService");

    if(isOnline()){
        URI uri = URI.create("http://myserver/Android/UploadImage/newAlert.php");
        new UpdateCheckAsyncTask(getHttpClient()).execute(uri); 
    }

}



boolean isOnline(){
    return ((GApplication)getApplication()).isOnline();
}

HttpClient getHttpClient(){
    return  ((GApplication)getApplication()).getHttpClient();
}

DatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper(){
    return  ((GApplication)getApplication()).getDatabaseHelper();
}



class UpdateCheckAsyncTask extends WebAsyncTaskBase{
    public UpdateCheckAsyncTask(HttpClient httpClient) {
        super(httpClient);
    }


    protected String doInBackground(URI... params) {
        return getHttpContent(params[0]);
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if(result == null){
            Log.i(TAG, "Call returned null");
            return;
        }
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processsing request");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            new BlogDbAsyncTask(getDatabaseHelper()).execute(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            if(e.getMessage() != null) Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    class BlogDbAsyncTask extends DbAsyncTaskBase<JSONObject, Boolean, BlogInfo>{

        public BlogDbAsyncTask(DatabaseHelper database) {
            super(database);
        }

        @Override
        protected BlogInfo doInBackground(JSONObject... json) {
            BlogInfo blogInfo = new BlogInfo();
            BlogDAO dao = new BlogDAO(GService.this, getDatabaseHelper());
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Adding new blog entry");
                Blog blog = dao.Select(json[0].getInt("FeedId"));
                if(blog.UID == null){
                    blog.UID = json[0].getInt("FeedId");
                    blog.Text = json[0].getString("Text");
                    blog.Title = json[0].getString("Header");
                    blog.PostedOn = json[0].getString("DisplayDate");
                    blog.PostedBy = "Gservice";
                    dao.Insert(blog);

                    blogInfo.Blog = blog;
                    blogInfo.IsNew = true;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                if(e.getMessage() != null) Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return blogInfo;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(BlogInfo result){


        }

    }

    class BlogInfo{
        public Blog Blog;
        public boolean IsNew;
    }
}
```

Probably the Onterminate method is never called in GApplication class which makes the service run continuously.Please Suggest if any issues can be found with this code.Also Suggest how to stop service if onterminate is never called in device..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find out what was causing the battery drain?

Comment: @JadeByfield It was my service causing the battery drain.I had Http requests in it.I am stopping the service in onpause and ondestroy of activity if it is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[onTerminate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29) isn't supposed to be called on real devices:

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never
>   be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed
>   by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is
>   executed when doing so.

you should consider using services instead, and use the appropriate one according to your needs.

if you wish to know when the app was "closed", you need to track the state of the activities. for example, you could have a global counter that counts the number of active activities. for each onCreate, you increase its value. for each onDestroy, you decrease its value. when it reaches 0, it means that no activity is currently active.

however, you should be warned that it's not quite accurate, since activities will be destroyed and re-created when the configuration has changed, so you will need to handle it too.

as i've mentioned, you should consider using a service instead. maybe bind to it on each activity that you need, and unbind when the activity was destroyed. maybe even make it run in the foreground and close it on demand... all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have stopped the service in Onpause() method of last activity of my application.

Comment: maybe instead of onPause, you should use onDestroy, and check isTaskRoot and only then stop the service. another alternative is to bind to the service in onResume and unbind from it in onPause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have a doubt.Even though my app is closed it still uses the Device CPU.Is there a way to control that?

Comment: if the service continues to do things in its background thread, you could add a way to close the thread (either gracefully by a flag or interrupt it if that's ok with you) . also, do note that even if an app seems to be closed, android might (and usually does) save the RAM and the process of the app in the near future, since there is a good chance the user will return to it.

Comment: Service stopped running after i stopped them.cpu usage after app closed is 25% to 30% which is a big problem.

Comment: question is if you have a thread that that keeps running. you know, a thread is totally separate from any class that you use, doesn't matter if a service holds it or an activity- it keeps running till it finishes the job or until you tell it to stop. my guess is that you have a thread (or more) that still runs. services and activities are just framework classes, they don't really do any magic but have their own behavior and lifecycle in the framework itself. they won't do anything to your variables unless you tell them to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `IntentService` instead of `Service`. This way the service will shut itself down once it completes the task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have stopped the service in Onpause() method of last activity of my application.